# NodeJS, multiple attempts at getting 360 angle between two points fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, vector

I'm trying to simple get the angle between two points in Node JS, I've gone though a few answers and none of them seem to work.

Here's what I've got so far as a test.js file.

```
function getDegree(x1,y1, x2,y2) {
    var dy = y2 - y1;
    var dx = x2 - x1;
    var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx); // range (-PI, PI]
    theta *= 180 / Math.PI; // rads to degs, range (-180, 180]

    // range [0, 360)
    if (theta < 0) {
        theta = 360 + theta;
    }

    return theta;
}

function output(expected, angle) {
    console.log('\n');
    var result = getDegree(angle[0], angle[1], angle[2], angle[3]);
    console.log('getDegree(' + angle + ') = ' + result);
    console.log('Expected: ' + expected + ', Result: ' + result + ' : ' + (expected == result));
}

var angle = [0,0, 0,0]; //(Current Pos), (Pos to Go to)

angle = [0,0,0,0];
output(0, angle);

angle = [0,0,0,9];
output(0, angle);

angle = [0,0,9,0];
output(90, angle);

angle = [0,0,0,-9];
output(180, angle);

angle = [0,0,-9,0];
output(270, angle);

// Should be 90ish
angle = [5,5,31,4];
output(90, angle);

module.exports = {
    getDegree: getDegree
};
```

And the output by running directly from node in the same directory.

```
var test = require('./test');

getDegree(0,0,0,0) = 0
Expected: 0, Result: 0 : true

getDegree(0,0,0,9) = 90
Expected: 0, Result: 90 : false

getDegree(0,0,9,0) = 0
Expected: 90, Result: 0 : false

getDegree(0,0,0,-9) = 270
Expected: 180, Result: 270 : false

getDegree(0,0,-9,0) = 180
Expected: 270, Result: 180 : false

// 90ish
getDegree(5,5,31,4) = 357.7974018382342
Expected: 90, Result: 357.7974018382342 : false
```

Comment: do you expect `getDegree(0,0,9,0)` to be `0` ? `Math.atan2(9, 0)` is 90 degree

Comment: Fast Snail you genius that worked. I'll accept an answer.

Comment: however it actually need y and x (as you did).but the angle direction you are looking for is different

Comment: It fails with ```angle = [31,16,31,4];``` but passes everything else :-?

Comment: that's a problem of your algorithm. you should think why `31,16,31,4`  you expected as 0 ??y is minus .when you translate it to 0,0 corrdinate you are drawing line downword

Comment: what is the expected angle for `angle = [31,16,31,4];`

Comment: i cannot believe that you expect `180` for `getDegree(0,0,0,-9)` and don't expect `180` for `getDegree(31,16,31,4);` which is same as `getDegree(0,0,0,-12);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle you are looking for is different from what `math.atan2` gives you.i made this image , try to understand it.

[image]

so what you can do ? swap y and x.

you should substitute angle from 90 .

```
θ -> 90-θ
tan(90- θ) = cot θ    // you can use this one too without interchanging x and y 
cot  θ = 1 / tan θ    // so that's why you should swap x and y
```

as you can see you have to use `1/tan θ` same as swapping y and x

```
var theta = Math.atan2(dx, dy);
```

Comment: Your comment is different to you're answer. The comment works, the answer does not?

Comment: Thanks, it fails with ```angle = [31,16,31,4];``` hmm but passes with everything else.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns no it doesn't fail .

 
i cannot believe that you expect `180` for `getDegree(0,0,0,-9)` and don't expect `180` for `getDegree(31,16,31,4);` which is same as `getDegree(0,0,0,-12);` can plz clarify